# What is the probability of right and left handedness given these probabilities?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Me and some friends were having a debate over one of the questions presented during a lecture. According to my one of friend, who attended the lecture, he said that the professor said the correct answer was $\frac{1}{16}$ and that $\frac{1}{4}$ was a "trick" answer.
[Mentioned question (Not allowed to embed pictures)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOPbs.png)


The way my friends approached the problem was to sketch out all the sample space, where L = Left-handed and R = Right-handed.
$$RR =\frac{9}{16}$$
$$RL =\frac{3}{16}$$
$$LR =\frac{3}{16}$$
$$LL =\frac{1}{16}$$
Then due to them knowing that $RR$ will never be an option, they removed it from the list, updated the denominator to 7 and got:
$$LL = \frac{1}{7}$$
Claiming the professor got none of the correct answers on his slide.


My approach was a little different. I saw it as a conditional probability problem. So I used Bayes Theorem:
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$
and ended out with:
$$LL = \frac{1}{16}$$

If anyone could please clarify on some of the theory behind this question and how you arrived at your result, what events you created etc, it would be a great help. We have really been boggled by this question, since both of our answers made sense to us. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of embedding a picture, please just type the professor's question.  Lots of people don't like to follow links.

Comment: I get $1/7$ also.  What do $A$ and $B$ stand for in your formula, and how do you get $1/16?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's do this as a conditional probability question.
The events in which we are interested are:

$B,$ at least one of the team's pitchers is left-handed. (That's a direct quote from the slide in the lecture.)

$A,$ the team has two left-handed pitchers. (That's what happens if you know at least one pitcher is left-handed and then you find out the other also is left-handed.)

We then have probabilities
$$ P(A) = \frac{1}{16} $$
(assuming each pitcher has an independent $\frac14$ chance to be left-handed),
$$ P(B) = 1 - P(\text{both are right-handed}) = 1 - \left(\frac34\right)^2 = \frac{7}{16},$$
and
$$ P(B\mid A) = 1 $$
since if $A$ is true then both pitchers are left-handed and it is then certainly true that *at least one of them* is left-handed.
Therefore
$$ P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(B\mid A)P(A)}{P(B)} 
= \frac{1\times\frac{1}{16}}{\frac{7}{16}} = \frac17,$$
so your friend is correct and the slide in the lecture is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Prob}{\mathbb{P}}$You should end up getting $1/7$ using your Bayes theorem method. If $A$ is the event of having two left-handers ($LL$) and $B$ is the event that there is at least one left-hander, then $\Prob(A) = 1/16, \Prob(B) = 1 - \Prob(RR) = 1-9/16 = 7/16$, and $\Prob\left(B\mid A\right) = 1$.